# SQL trigger for fiscal year in Oracle Apex

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have this code to get the fiscal year.

```
from
(SELECT

CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)WHEN 1 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 
WHEN 2 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1
WHEN 3 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1
ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
END
AS PR_YEAR  , 


CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
    WHEN 04 THEN 1
    WHEN 05 THEN 1
    WHEN 06 THEN 1
    WHEN 07 THEN 1
    WHEN 08 THEN 1
    WHEN 09 THEN 1
    WHEN 10 THEN 2
    WHEN 11 THEN 2
    WHEN 12 THEN 2
    WHEN 01 THEN 2
    WHEN 02 THEN 2
    WHEN 03 THEN 2
END AS  PR_MONTH
 FROM dual)
```

I want to use a trigger to insert the data that the previous code throws me in a column name **Fiscaly** from a Oracle DataBase table name **MM_Inventory** for Apex and I have it like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER add_fiscaly
BEFORE INSERT ON MM_Inventory
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT PR_YEAR||PR_MONTH
from
(SELECT

CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)WHEN 1 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 
WHEN 2 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1
WHEN 3 THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1
ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
END
AS PR_YEAR  , 


CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
    WHEN 04 THEN 1
    WHEN 05 THEN 1
    WHEN 06 THEN 1
    WHEN 07 THEN 1
    WHEN 08 THEN 1
    WHEN 09 THEN 1
    WHEN 10 THEN 2
    WHEN 11 THEN 2
    WHEN 12 THEN 2
    WHEN 01 THEN 2
    WHEN 02 THEN 2
    WHEN 03 THEN 2
END AS  PR_MONTH
 FROM dual)
END;
```

But I don't know what is wrong or missing to make it work, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an INTO clause in the trigger here:

```
SELECT PR_YEAR||PR_MONTH
  INTO :NEW.Fiscaly
from ...
```

I believe this simplified code achieves the same thing:

```
create or replace TRIGGER add_fiscaly
BEFORE INSERT ON MM_Inventory
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.Fiscaly :=  CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE) < 4
                       THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 
                       ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
                    END
                    || CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE) BETWEEN 4 AND 9
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE 2
                       END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I got this message: "Error at line 31: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:". The line is ```END AS  PR_MONTH
 FROM dual)```

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon after `FROM dual)` to end the statement.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.  I appreciate your help